# How can i change the default path of PowerShell exe

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-terminal

I have installed PowerShell using the `scoop` package manager on my system. However, even after installation, the system still refers to the old path of PowerShell.

I have tried adding the new path of the new PowerShell installation to the environment variables, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here is the output of the `where.exe` command for PowerShell:

```
where.exe Powershell
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
where.exe pwsh
E:\Apps\scoop\apps\powershell\current\pwsh.exe
E:\Apps\scoop\shims\pwsh.exe
```

Due to this behavior, I am unable to use the newly installed PowerShell through Scoop in my **Windows Terminal** and **VS Code**.

[image]

[image]

How can I change this behavior where the system continues to refer to the old path of PowerShell despite installing it with Scoop? I need to ensure that the new PowerShell installation is recognized and used by my Windows Terminal and VS Code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your issue. PowerShell version 6.x and up are **not** a replacement of the Windows PowerShell. They exist next to each other and can both be used.  The newer versions are refered to as `PowerShell` while the legacy version is called `Windows PowerShell`.

Comment: @Olaf I'm feeling confused as I had thought that PowerShell Core 7 was a replacement for Windows PowerShell. However, after doing some research, I discovered that it is indeed the same as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

- For vscode profile i open `setting.json` and add:

```json
     "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell Core": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell Core"
```

- For Windows Terminal, I simply create a new profile and modified the path to the `pwsh` executable.

> To find the exact path of `pwsh.exe`, I typed `where.exe pwsh` in the terminal.